# how does writeToFile Function in flutter returns null value?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Here I am tring to Download a csv file from Firebase storage in my flutter application?

```
Future<void> _downloadFile(StorageReference ref,url) async {
    final String uuid = Uuid().v1();
    print(uuid);
    final http.Response downloadData = await http.get(url);
    print(downloadData.body);
    final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
    print(systemTempDir);
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    print(tempPath);
    final File tempFile = File('${tempPath}/tmp$uuid.csv');
    if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
      await tempFile.delete();
    }
    await tempFile.create();
    assert(await tempFile.readAsString() == "");
    print(tempFile);
    final StorageFileDownloadTask task = ref.writeToFile(tempFile);
    final int byteCount = (await task.future).totalByteCount;
    final String tempFileContents = await tempFile.readAsString();


    final String fileContents = downloadData.body;
    final String name = await ref.getName();
    final String bucket = await ref.getBucket();
    final String path = await ref.getPath();
    print(fileContents);
  }
```

It returns an error saying that writeToFile was called on null.

Comment: Can you please share the exact error message?

Comment: ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'writeToFile' was called on null.
E/flutter (17182): Receiver: null
E/flutter (17182): Tried calling: writeToFile(Instance of '_File')
E/flutter (17182): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)

Comment: Well obviously, `ref` is `null`. Can you share the part of the code where you call `_downloadFile()`?

Comment: @AaswinSinha `StorageReference ref` is null

Comment: new RaisedButton(onPressed: ()=>_downloadFile(ref,document["DownloadURL"])),

Comment: it's still unclear how do you get ref, probably you pass null to the function arguments

Comment: Howto get Storage Refrence>?

Comment: How to get storage reference to a firebase storage???